# AWS QuickSight Timeline Gantt

Tags: amazon-web-services, timeline, gantt-chart, amazon-quicksight

I have data in my DB of my residential history, with start date and end dates. and different countries I have lived in.

For tax purpose I am trying to plot a chart to determine how many days in a financial year I have spent in a particular country.

Is there a way I can plot my residential timeline on a graph ?
doesn’t need to be financial year, Even If I am Able to plot it based on Calendar Year, I will have something to build on top of.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to create a Gantt chart in AWS Quicksight too but there isn't a built-in Gantt visualization in AWS Quicksight.

However, I was able to build a Gantt chart using Plotly express.

https://plotly.com/python/gantt/

For your use case, you can probably plot your residential history as a Gantt chart using the code below

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Country="USA", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28'),
    dict(Country="Canada", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15'),
    dict(Country="France", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30')
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Country", color="Country")
fig.show()
```

[Residential History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnKBj.png)